# Python edit line from txt file

Tags: python

I'm making program that open txt file and replace first 0 with 1 of given line. Now it only print the edited line, but I want that it prints all the lines. I'm using python 3.1.

```
line_number = 3
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    number = 0
    for line in f:
        number += 1
        if line_number == number:
            content = line.replace("0","1",1)
savefile = filename[:4] + ".tmp"
with open(savefile, "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
os.remove(filename)
os.rename(savefile, filename)
```

Text file:

```
0 Dog
0 Cat
0 Giraffe
0 Leopard
0 Bear
```

Comment: Output in the loop

Comment: I think you do not need of `tmp` file to to this. `remove` and `rename` are also redundant.

Comment: See [**`fileinput`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) for in-place editing of files.

Comment: @PeterWood, very good idea. `fileinput` will be a more "natural" solution of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write each unchanged line to the `savefile`:

```
import os
filename = 'input.txt'

line_number = 3
savefile = filename[:4] + ".tmp"
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    with open(savefile, "w") as fout:
        number = 0
        for line in f:
            number += 1
            if line_number == number:
                content = line.replace("0","1",1)
                fout.write(content)
            else:
                # Write unchanged lines here
                fout.write(line)
os.remove(filename)
os.rename(savefile, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
filename = "./test.txt"

with open(filename) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# the element with index 2 is the 3-th element
lines[2] = lines[2].replace("0","1",1)

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        [f.write(line) for line in lines]
```

Output(`./test.txt`):

```
0 Dog
0 Cat
1 Giraffe
0 Leopard
0 Bear
```

You can read the file and save it to a list. Then you can then perform a certain action for each item(or for a specific element) in the list and save the result in the same file. You don't need of `.tmp` file or to remove and rename a file.

**Edit:**
There is an another approach with [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) (thanks to @PeterWood)

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input(files=('test.txt',), inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        if fileinput.lineno() is 3:
            print(line.replace("0", "1", 1).strip())
        else:
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: he only wants to change 0 to 1 in line 3, it wasn't super clear to me at first either.

Comment: @d_kennetz, you are right. I already edited the answer. Thanks.